# Spring AMQP MessageProperties:all headers were removed during deadlettering

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I have got a question about Spring AMQP Message:
During processing I was able to update headers of message properties in String AMQP Message with some specific values.
After DeadLettering of this message, all specific headers were disappeared/removed.

Is this behaviour correct ? 
Looking forward to your response.
Regards, Anton.

---

spring-rabbit.version: 1.3.5.RELEASE
spring.version: 4.1.1.RELEASE

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broker knows nothing about your client-side consumer changes; the original message (with its orignal headers) is dead-lettered by the broker (with an `x-death` header added to indicate the reason - rejection, expiry etc).

In order to do what you want, you need to publish your modified message yourself rather than using dead-lettering.

See the [RepublishMessageRecoverer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#async-listeners) for an example using Spring retry. You can make a custom recover, or simply catch the exception in your listener to republish.

Comment: The reason to try such approach with DLX is simplicity of dead lettering. =)
Also there are a lot of useful answers from you about 'recoverer' stuff. 
One question about this: if I don't need a 'retry' at all, so I've set maxAttempts to zero:
 
RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
   .withMaxAttempts(0)
   .setRecoverer(new MyRecoverer(), "bar", "baz"))
   .build(); 
and faced with an issue, that Throwable cause was null in MyRecoverer#recover(Message message, Throwable cause);

So, it is not possible to use zero max attempts? 
Or may be exists some other valid approach? 
Thanks.

Comment: `maxAttempts` is max delivery attempts, not max retry attempts; so it needs to be at least 1.

Comment: In case of RetryInterceptorBuilder#maxAttempts(int maxAttempts), this maxAttempts value setted to the SimpleRetryPolicy#setMaxAttempts(int retryAttempts). From the doc: 
  * Setter for retry attempts.
  *
  * \\@param retryAttempts the number of attempts before a retry becomes
  * impossible.
  
So, what did you mean in terms of 'delivery'? Thanks, Anton.

Comment: In this context, I meant message `delivery` to the listener from the listener container. I issued a [Pull Request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/pull/20) last Friday to improve the javadocs.